# Python - 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using Python 2.6 and Jinja2 to create HTML reports. I provide the template with many results and the template loops through them and creates HTML tables

When calling template.render, I've suddenly started getting this error.

```
<td>{{result.result_str}}</td>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The strange thing is, even if I set result.result_str to a simple ascii string like "abc" for every result, I am still seeing this error. I'm new to Jinja2 and Python and would appreciate any ideas on how I can go about investigating the problem to get to the root cause.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you get an error with a string like "ABC", maybe the non-ASCII character is somewhere else. In the template source perhaps?

In any case, use Unicode strings throughout your application to avoid this kind of problems. If your data source provides you with byte strings, you get unicode strings with `byte_string.decode('utf-8')`, if the string is encoded in UTF-8. If your source is a file, use the `StreamReader` class in the codecs module.

If you're unsure about the difference between Unicode strings and regular strings, read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I checked template for non ascii, in Vim I ran "set isprint=", but it didn't show anything non ascii.

Comment: And there's no other variable, that the template would try to render after the line you showed in your post, that could contain and encoded string? If not, can you reduce your template to the bare minimum that will reproduce the error?

Comment: Good idea. I'll try just displaying the result_str and nothing else  to see if I still get it.

Answer (score 78):

Try to add this:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

It fixed my problem, good luck.

Comment: This is the best answer in the thread, saves a lot of hassle.

Comment: What is the trick with reload() ? is it sorcery ? (note: it does works but I don't understand)

Comment: I don't really understand why this works, but it does. Thanks

Comment: This is actually **terrible advice**. The OP should instead make sure they decode byte strings to Unicode values first. Setting the default encoding is akin to keeping walking on a broken leg by strapping a stick to it instead of getting yourself to a hospital to set the bone.

Comment: I accidentally upvoted this answer because it seemed to provide a quick fix. @MartijnPieters is right though: You should fix your bugs instead.

Comment: If I genuinely want everything to be UTF-8, why is this wrong?

Answer (score 43):

From http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#unicode

> Jinja2 is using Unicode internally which means that you have to pass Unicode objects to the render function or bytestrings that only consist of ASCII characters.

So wherever you set result.result_str, you need to make it unicode, e.g.

```
result.result_str = unicode(my_string_variable, "utf8")
```

(If your bytes were utf8 encoded unicode)

or

```
result.result_str = u"my string"
```

Comment: This answer helped me more than the accepted. I can agree with the advice in the accepted answer -- it would be fantastic if I could take a month and fix my 100k SLOC webapp to correctly convert strings to unicode at its boundaries and only work with unicode internally! -- but I can't follow that advice because of dollars. Knowing that Jinja2 is using unicode internally helped me recognize at what point I was having encoding problems, and write a fix to solve the production bug. Thanks, guys!

Comment: Is it possible to patch Jinja2 so that it tries to decode from `utf-8` instead of `ascii`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642781/hack-jinja2-to-encode-from-utf-8-instead-of-ascii

Answer (score 11):

Just encountered the same problem in a piece of code which saves output from Jinja2 to HTML files:

```
with open(path, 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(template.render(...))
```

It's easy to blame Jinja2, although the actual problem is in Python's `open()` which as of version 2.7 doesn't support UTF-8. The fix is as simple as:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(path, 'wb', 'utf-8') as fh:
    fh.write(template.render(...))
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple strings may contain UTF-8 character bytes but they are not of type unicode. This can be fixed by "decode" which converts str to unicode. Works in Python 2.5.5.

my_string_variable.decode("utf8")

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is a 7-bit code.  The value 0xC4 cannot be stored in 7 bits. Therefore, you are using the wrong encoding for that data.

Comment: I understand what the error means. I'm looking for some pointers on tracking down why I am getting it.

Comment: @shane: Because you're using `0xC4`.  Find this character.  Remove it.

Comment: @shane: It's probably worth noting that 0xc4 is the first byte of [UTF8-encoded characters between U+0100 and U+013F](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256&unicodeinhtml=hex).

Answer (score -1):

Or you may do

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
```

in your console where you run the script.