# How to handle my UnicodeDecodeError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2

My datastore contains values and I want my form to enable updating of those values. I use wtforms in jinja2 with google app engine. I get an error message that I cannot understand:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bnano-www/wtform.356204665143172839/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bnano-www/wtform.356204665143172839/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bnano-www/wtform.356204665143172839/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bnano-www/wtform.356204665143172839/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bnano-www/wtform.356204665143172839/handler.py", line 152, in dispatch
    response = super(NewBaseHandler, self).dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bnano-www/wtform.356204665143172839/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bnano-www/wtform.356204665143172839/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bnano-www/wtform.356204665143172839/handler.py", line 101, in check_login
    return handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bnano-www/wtform.356204665143172839/handler.py", line 881, in get
    self.render_jinja('details.html', **data)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bnano-www/wtform.356204665143172839/handler.py", line 119, in render_jinja
    **template_args))
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bnano-www/wtform.356204665143172839/webapp2_extras/jinja2.py", line 158, in render_template
    return self.environment.get_template(_filename).render(**context)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~bnano-www/wtform.356204665143172839/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "template_files/details.html", line 78, in top-level template code
    <dd> {{ form.address|safe }} </dd>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The code I have is ordinary:

```
class UpdateForm(Form):       
    address = TextField(_('Address'), [validators.Required()])
    zipcode = TextField(_('Zip code'), [validators.Required()])
    email = TextField(_('Email'), [validators.Required()])

class UpdateHandler(NewBaseHandler):

    @user_required
        def get(self):

        user = auth_models.User.get_by_id(long(self.auth.get_user_by_session()['user_id']))

        userinfo = self.auth.get_user_by_session()
        if user.address:
            address = user.address#.decode('utf-8')
            logging.info('user info:'+str(userinfo))

        if user:
            data = {'user': user, 'address': address, 'form':UpdateForm(obj=user)}
            self.render_jinja('details.html', **data)

    @user_required
    def post(self, sponsor=None):
        user = \
            auth_models.User.get_by_id(long(self.auth.get_user_by_session()['user_id'
                ]))
        user.address = UpdateForm(self.request.params).address.data
        user.put()
        self.render_jinja('details.html', user=user, sponsor=sponsor, form=UpdateForm(obj=user))
```

I wonder what I can do to adjust the problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

### Update

Experimentally I found that doing this handled the error:
`result.result_str = unicode(my_string_variable, "utf8")`
I would still like to avoid having to manipulate all the strings I use though.

### Solved(?)

Last time I checked the problem did not occur. I suspect this being a problem with my test data being latin-1 so I cleared my test data. Thanks for all the help here.

Comment: result.result_str = unicode(my_string_variable, "utf8") : As suggested by you, fixed the issue. Thanks a lot. Was stuck on this for few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's an encoding error. I see you have already tried adding `.decode('utf-8')`. But have you tried to encode the string that cause the error like this `.encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is still not working. I tried everything even not manipulating the strings at all which should work since then it should be treated as unicode. I suspect there might be something with Jinja2 that is causing this so I'll look more closely how that handles unicode.

Comment: Ok. What you could do is to print (or output in other way) the type of the strings you have like this `print 'user.adress =', type(user.address)`. Do this on all the strings you have and make sure thay are the same. Don't mix unicode and none unicode...

Comment: Thanks! It says `user.adress = <type 'str'>` when I suppose it should say `user.adress = <type 'unicode'>`. Is there something wrong with my input? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry. Dunno if I can help you more because i don't know jinja2 :-/ Just want to make sure that you know about prefixing a string with a `u` makes it unicode like this: `a_string = u'some random text'`. If you mixing in our own string (that are not fetched from the form) without doing that, it may be the problem. But from the code snippet you show us you don't seem to do that. And I think you may already know about that. I hope someone else is able to get you further...

Comment: Thanks Niclas for all the help. I'm clearing my test data thinking that this was that my test data was latin-1 or some other encoding since this problem does not happen with new entities.

Comment: Oh. Ok, sounds resonable. Good luck then :-)

Answer (score 6):

I use GAE and Jinja2 as well. And I happened to catch this error with cyrillic symbols.
So these 3 strings of code helped me out (and I didn't want to ".encode" all of my strings manually in the code).

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

This was pointed out by Richard Huang here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14919377/605952