# SqlAlchemy not using utf8 charset even if specified

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask with Flask-SqlAlchemy with MySQL and my connection string does have the `charset-utf8` parameter on my connection string.

I'm also using reflection and my Model is specified as this:

```
class Value(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'values'
    __tablename__ = 'values'
```

I've also tried the trick of putting `# -*- coding:utf8 -*-` inside my files but I'm still getting these stacktraces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_debugtoolbar/__init__.py", line 125, in dispatch_request
    return view_func(**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cProfile.py", line 149, in runcall
    return func(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/application/views/player.py", line 54, in player_show
    return render_template('player/show.html', **locals())
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 128, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 110, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/application/templates/player/show.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "base.html" %}
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/application/templates/base.html", line 62, in top-level template code
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  File "/home/numkem/src/sd/application/templates/player/show.html", line 27, in block "body"
    <td>{{ field.values }}</td>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why is the charset ignored on connection? Shouldn't it be set by the connection string? Maybe it's just not something that possible/supported when using reflections.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not really coming from SqlAlchemy but more from Jinja2 itself since it wasn't seeing that I wanted to use utf8 encoding througout the application. the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=unicode#unicode) states that the default encoding is set to ascii if nothing is specified.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040532/python-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte) shows the solution to my problem.

The fix is to add this to your first code:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

I'm not 100% familiar with python but I'm assuming this might have to do with using a WSGI application instead of a standard script so the `# -*- coding:utf8 -*-` trick doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you pass non-unicode strings in your templates as context, because Jinja2 supports only unicode.

You should read this [material](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.encoding) about encoding.

Comment: The data comes from SqlAlchemy, I'm able to see it appear correctly outside of the template. Starting to think it might have to do with Jinja itself rather than SqlAlchemy